# How to release pst file after creating it using Redemption API?

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I am simply converting a list of message files to a combined pst. Below is my code:

```
RDOSession pstSession = new RDOSession(); 
RDOPstStore store = null;
var pstPath = "D:\\test\\combined.pst";
store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(pstPath, 1, "combinedPST");
RDOMail rdo_Mail = 
   pstSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(dr["FullPathOfMessageFile"].ToString());
rdo_Mail.CopyTo(store.IPMRootFolder);
rdo_Mail.Save();
store.Save();
pstSession.Logoff();
```

This is a windows form application. Running above code creates a file combined.pst in the test folder. When I try to open this pst in outlook, outlook prompts that this pst is currently being used by another process. After I close my win from application, pst can be loaded. 
I think redemption API is locking the created PST. What am I missing? What other object do I need to dispose?

Comment: try setting pstSession and store objects to null

Comment: tried but did not work. Creating a separate process for creating pst might do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PST provider keeps a PST file referenced and loaded for 30 minutes for the performance reasons. Or until the PST provider dll itself gets unloaded (e.g. when the host process terminates).
You might want to play with the registry key mentioned in http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=222328

Comment: page in the given link does not exits. I did not understand.

Comment: What if I add a separate console project, add this logic there and later access it from my win from application creating a process. Will it work? Can I release the created pst then?

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko, When I created a separate process, I am having an issue. Pst file is successfully created but when I load this pst in outlook 2013, no any email message is there and also the size of pst is decreased after loading. There is no any error when running the code. What might be the possible issue?

Comment: It means the data was not completely flushed and Outlook truncates it. Make sure you explicitly release all Redemption objects using Marshal.ReleaseComObject and void using multiple dot notation.

Comment: Actually saw your answer to my another [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453650/created-pst-file-using-redemption-api-is-empty-when-loaded-in-microsoft-outlook/47463325#47463325) Will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a console application (exe) and add the logic of creating pst there. Later execute this exe creating a process in your application. In this way, the generated pst is not locked and you can move, modify or delete the file.