# Created PST file using Redemption API is empty when loaded in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: c#, process, outlook, outlook-redemption

Environment: I have a windows console application and I am running the exe from command line.
Below is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   CreatePSTUsingRedemption(args[0], args[1]);
 }
 private static void CreatePSTUsingRedemption(string messageFilePath, string pstPath)
 {       
   RDOSession pstSession = new RDOSession();
   RDOPstStore store = null;
   store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(pstPath, 1, "combinedPST");
   //actually there is a loop here to loop through each message files.
   RDOMail rdo_Mail = pstSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(messageFilePath);
   rdo_Mail.CopyTo(store.IPMRootFolder);
   rdo_Mail.Save();
   store.Save();
   completedCount++;
   Console.WriteLine("FILES_PROCESSED:" + completedCount);
   pstSession.Logoff();
 }
```

Main purpose of this code is to create a single pst file combining email message(.msg) files.
Now when I run the exe, a pst file is created in the given location and its size keeps increasing as the code runs. After all the message files are processed application exists. There is no any error. Now, when I try to load this pst file in Outlook 2013. Pst is empty and its size is also reduced to 265KB every time. I don't think any process is using this pst because I can copy and move it anywhere I want. What might be the issue? Any suggestion, please?

**UPDATE 1**

```
private static void CreatePSTUsingRedemption(XmlNodeList nodelist, string pstPath)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        RDOSession pstSession = null;
        RDOPstStore store = null;
        RDOFolder folder = null;
        RDOMail rdo_Mail = null;
        try
        {
            pstSession = new RDOSession();
            store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(pstPath, 1, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pstPath));             
            var enumerator = store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.GetEnumerator(); //DELETE DEFAULT FOLDERS
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var defaultFolders = enumerator.Current as RDOFolder;
                    defaultFolders.Delete();
            }
            int completedCount = 0;
            folder = store.IPMRootFolder;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
            {
                rdo_Mail = pstSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(node["FullPath"].InnerText);              
                rdo_Mail.CopyTo(folder);
                rdo_Mail.Save();
                store.Save();
                completedCount++;
                Console.WriteLine("FILES_PROCESSED:" + completedCount);                              
            }            
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo_Mail);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
        }
        pstSession.Logoff();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pstSession);
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Above is my code for the actual loop. I am loading all the email messages file path from an xml file. I still encounter same issue as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an indication that the PST store is not fully flushed to the disk and Outlook "fixes' the PST file by resetting it.

Try to explicitly release all Redemption objects first before logging off and call GC.Collect(). If you have a loop processing multiple files, release the message on each step of the loop.

```
 private static void CreatePSTUsingRedemption(string messageFilePath, string pstPath)
 {       
   RDOSession pstSession;
   try
   {
     RDOPstStore store;
     RDOFolder folder;
     RDOMail rdo_Mail;
     pstSession = new RDOSession();
     store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(pstPath, 1, "combinedPST");
     //actually there is a loop here to loop through each message files.
     rdo_Mail = pstSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(messageFilePath);
     folder = store.IPMRootFolder;
     rdo_Mail.CopyTo(folder);
     rdo_Mail.Save();
     store.Save();
     completedCount++;
     Console.WriteLine("FILES_PROCESSED:" + completedCount);
   }
   finally
   {
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo_Mail);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
   }
   pstSession.Logoff(); 
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pstSession);
   GC.Collect();
 }
```

Comment: which com objects do I need to release inside the loop? Is it rdo_Mail and folder?

Comment: RDOMail. Folder is used on all iterations of the loop, so it need to be retrieved before starting the loop and must released after the loop exits. Also make sure you don't use multipel dot notation (like RDOFolder.Items.Add).

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I have added an update (Update1) to my question with my actual code using the loop. I did what you said but still having the same issue. Could you please verify the code? I have retrieved redemption objects before the loop and released them after the loop but sill not fixing the issue. Is it due to the use of multiple dot notations to delete default folders?Also, I need to add some custom folders as well. I need to create customs folders as per email message logical path. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, store.IPMRootFolder.Folders.GetEnumerator is nto a good idea. You might also want to avoid using enumerators since .Net tends to keep all collection items referenced.

Comment: What is the better way to check if a folder exists and create a new one if it does not? I need to do this inside the loop. For example:- if my message has a logical path of (albert_meyers_000_1_1.pst > Personal folders > meyers-a > ExMerge - Meyers, Albert > Sent Items > FW: FW: Laid-Off A No Nothing Production.msg), I need to create folder accordingly. And this logical path is not same for each email message. Please suggest.

Comment: Call RDOFolders.Item("FolderName"). If it returns null, call RDOFolders.Add("FolderName").